# Call modal from one sibling component to other angular

Tags: javascript, angular, service, bootstrap-4, angular6

I have this Angular6 component arquitecture in my app 
Main component

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
```

Dashboard component

```
<app-meseros>
</app-meseros>
<app-ultimospedidos></app-ultimospedidos>
<app-modal></app-modal>
```

I want to call modal from navbar.component, my modal is on dashboard on component modal.component

This is what i have tried

```
<!--navbar.component.html -->
<a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal()">Crear pedido</a> 

<!--navbar.component.ts -->
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BootstrapService } from '../../services/bootstrap.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public bootstrapService: BootstrapService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  openModal() {
    this.bootstrapService.toggle();
  }
}
```

I created a service so i can communicate between my navbar.component and modal.component, this is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BootstrapService {
  isOpen: any = false;
  constructor() {}
  toggle() {
    console.log(!this.isOpen);
    return (this.isOpen = !this.isOpen);
  }
}
```

Then in modal.component.ts i want to subscribe to these changes so i can launch modal on boolean value change.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BootstrapService } from '../../services/bootstrap.service';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  isOpen;
  closeResult: string;
  modalname: string;
  constructor(
    public modalService: NgbModal,
    public bootstrapService: BootstrapService
  ) {}
  open(content) {
    // console.log(this.bootstrapService.popup);
    this.modalService
      .open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' })
      .result.then(
        result => {
          this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        },
        reason => {
          this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        }
      );
  }
  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bootstrapService.toggle().subscribe(isOpen => {
      this.isOpen = isOpen;
      console.log(isOpen);
    });
  }
}
```

Im not even able to subscribe to the change from bootstrapService, i get following error, 
RROR in src/app/components/modal/modal.component.ts(41,36): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'boolean'.

if i try to subscribe to value on service like this

```
this.bootstrapService.isOpen.subscribe(isOpen => {
  this.isOpen = isOpen;
  console.log(isOpen);
});
```

i get error on console from browser which says

DashboardComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.bootstrapService.isOpen.subscribe is not a function

i hope someone can shade some light on this approach, and if this is the best approach to take on this kind of implementations, thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved it! what was happening first was that i was calling EventEmitter from wrong library (visual studio autoimported wrong, i needed to import from @angular/core

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, i was calling wrong EventEmitter from wrong library, this is updated working code

first i call service from component where i want to call my modal

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BootstrapService } from '../../services/bootstrap.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public bootstrapService: BootstrapService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  openModal() {
    this.bootstrapService.toggle();
  }
}
```

Then i emit my changes so i can subscribe from modal component

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BootstrapService {
  isOpen: any = 'isOpen';
  @Output() change: any = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}
  toggle() {
    this.change.emit(this.isOpen);
    console.log(this.isOpen);
  }
}

i reference my template with `@ViewChild('crearpedido') modalInstance;`
and finally subscribe to changes, call modal on subscribe changes.

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BootstrapService } from '../../services/bootstrap.service';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  isOpen;
  closeResult: string;
  @ViewChild('crearpedido') modalInstance;
  constructor(
    public modalService: NgbModal,
    public bootstrapService: BootstrapService
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bootstrapService.change.subscribe(isOpen => {
      this.isOpen = isOpen;
      console.log(this.isOpen);
      this.modalService.open(this.modalInstance);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is working repo!!
https://github.com/soyisraelortiz/componentscommunication